# How to pass the variable argument to the MYSQL database query in a python Tkinter program

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, python-3.7

I'm doing with a simple code to print the details of a row by inputting the `Roll_No` number of the table which contains 4 columns in the likes of:

```
'Roll_No', 'name', 'age', 'city'
```

But unable to pass the user input from the `Entry` box in Tkinter to the query statement of MySQL function

```
def detail():
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM personal_info WHERE (Roll_No = ?)", et1.get()) 
    mydata = mycursor.fetchall()
    for row in mydata: 
        et1.delete(0, END)
        et1.insert(0,row[0])
        et2.insert(0,row[1])
        et3.insert(0,row[2])
        et4.insert(0,row[3])
```

when running it the cmd shows as below:

Expected to pass the input from `et1` `Entry` box in the Tkinter to the query function.

**But it shows manual syntax error in the execution line**.

> Copy form comment:
>
> ```
> prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params) 
> raise ValueError("Could not process parameters") 
> ValueError: Could not process parameters
> ```

Comment: what the error you are getting

Comment: Should be probably `... WHERE (Roll_No = ?)", (et1.get(),)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing python variable to sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684090/passing-python-variable-to-sql)

Comment: @Thiluxan: It would be much simpler to help you if you [edit] your Question and show the **Full Traceback** you get. Please **copy** the error message as it shows, don't describe it with your own words.

Comment: @Thiluxan: Looks like you have **hidden** the `mysql` Traceback. Disable it with `# raise ValueError...` to get the **real Traceback** . Have you tried: `... WHERE (Roll_No = ?)", (et1.get(),)`?